# How to access attributes of NodeList elements in Protractor

Tags: javascript, html, protractor, nodelist

I'm trying to read values from a fairly big HTML table in Protractor (about a thousand rows and 5 columns).
Protractor's element.all().getText() method is very slow at this, so I decided to implement a solution using browser.executeScript to read the values directly, like:

```
async getTextFromHtmlTable(){
    try{
        var rows = element.all(by.css('table[id^="P"] tr'));
        var numRows = await rows.count();
        var arrRows = [];

        for (var i = 2; i <= numRows; i++){
            console.log("********Processing row: " + i);
            var css = 'table[id^=\"P\"] tr:nth-child(' + i + ') td div div';
            //**Slow solution: var arrRowsText = await element.all(by.css(css)).getText();

            //Faster:
            var arrRowsText = await browser.executeScript("return document.querySelectorAll('" + css + "')").then(function(elements){
                var arrayRes = [];
                for (var j=0; j<elements.length; j++){
                    console.log("****** Element text: " + elements[j].textContent);
                    arrayRes.push(elements[j].textContent);    
                }

                return arrayRes;
            });

            arrRows.push(arrRowsText.join(';').replace(/;\s/gm, ";"));

        }
        return arrRows; 
    }catch(err){
        console.log ('Some error: ' + err)
    }; 
}
```

However, console output when executing the test is:

********Processing row: 569
****** Element text: undefined
****** Element text: undefined
****** Element text: undefined
****** Element text: undefined
****** Element text: undefined
********Processing row: 570
****** Element text: undefined
****** Element text: undefined
****** Element text: undefined
****** Element text: undefined
****** Element text: undefined

No matter what attribute I read (textContent, innerText, innerHTML...), it always returns 'undefined'. Am I doing anything wrong? Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

I finally found a solution to this, DublinDev pointed me in the right direction when he said that executeScript does not return NodeLists. So I thought about processing the NodeList inside the executeScript method and have it return an array of texts instead of the actual NodeList:

```
var arrRowsText = await browser.executeScript("return (function(){" +
            "var nodes = document.querySelectorAll('" + css + "');" +
            "var arrayRes = [];" +
            "for (var j=0; j<nodes.length; j++){" +
            "  arrayRes.push(nodes[j].innerText);" +
            "}" +
            "return arrayRes;" +
            "})();");
```

Now it works like a charm and element texts are read much faster with innerText than with getText().

Answer (score 0):

It appears that nodelists are returned through the `executeScript` method as an array of webElements so `getText()` should work. You also don't need to use `.then()` when something is already `await`ed. Can you try the below code?

```
async getTextFromHtmlTable(){
  try{
      var rows = element.all(by.css('table[id^="P"] tr'));
      var numRows = await rows.count();
      var arrRows = [];

      for (var i = 2; i <= numRows; i++){
          console.log("********Processing row: " + i);
          var css = 'table[id^=\"P\"] tr:nth-child(' + i + ') td div div';
          //**Slow solution: var arrRowsText = await element.all(by.css(css)).getText();

          //Faster:
          var arrRowsText = await browser.executeScript("return document.querySelectorAll('" + css + "')");
          let allEleText = [];
          for(let j = 0; j < arrRowsText.length; j++){
            allEleText.push(await arrRowsText[j].getText());
          }

          arrRows.push(allEleText.join(';').replace(/;\s/gm, ";"));
      }
      return arrRows; 
  }catch(err){
      console.log ('Some error: ' + err)
  }; 
}
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion and it works, but the downside is that getText() is very slow, as I said (about 7 minutes to retrieve text of 1,000 rows with 5 columns), and I wanted to try a different and faster approach instead of using WebElements. So maybe there's no way to access the attributes of an HTML node with Protractor?